# Tax implications of diversification

Tags: united-states, taxes, diversification

I have a question about diversifying some investments. For the purposes of my question you can assume that this is not retirement investing, and that I have a diversified retirement plan already in place. Also, I'm mainly concerned with the US tax implications (or any other implications relevant to a US investor).

Let's say I invested $10,000US in a stock 10 years ago. In the intervening 10 years, it has gone up 10x and is now worth $100,000US. That seems like a lot to have in a single stock, so I'd like to diversify it by moving that money into either other stocks or some other vehicle.

My understanding (and please correct me if I'm wrong), is that to diversify, I'd need to sell some number of shares and would then have to pay long term capital gains (15%?) on the difference between purchase and sale price. Is that right? So if I wanted to sell half of it, I paid $5,000 for it and sold it for $50,000, I'd owe 15% on $45,000 = $6750.00 in taxes.

Do I have that right? If so, are there ways to reduce the amount of taxes owed? Given that it's currently December, I suppose I could sell half of what I want now, and the other half in January and it would split the tax burden over 2 years instead, but beyond that, are there any strategies for tax reduction in this scenario?

Are there any reasons why this wouldn't be a good idea to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, to change which stocks you owe you need to sell one and buy the other, which for tax purposes means taking the profit or loss accrued up to then. On the other hand this establishes a new baseline, so you will not be double-faced on those gains. It just makes a mess of this year's tax return, and forced you to set aside some if the money to cover that.

Answer (score 5):

(All for US.)

**Yes you (will) have a realized long-term capital gain, which is taxable.** Long-term gains (including those distributed by a mutual fund or other RIC, and also 'qualified' dividends, both not relevant here) are taxed at **lower rates** than 'ordinary' income but are **still bracketed** almost (not quite) like ordinary income, **not always 15%**.

Specifically if your ordinary taxable income (after deductions and exemptions, equivalent to line 43 *minus* LTCG/QD) 'ends' in the 25% to 33% brackets, your LTCG/QD income is taxed at 15% unless the total of ordinary+preferred reaches the top of those brackets, then any remainder at 20%. These brackets depend on your filing status and are adjusted yearly for inflation, for 2016 they are:
* single 37,650 to 413,350
* married-joint or widow(er) 75,300 to 413,350
* head-of-household 50,400 to 441,000 (special)
* married-separate 37,650 to 206,675
which I'd guess covers at least the middle three quintiles of the earning/taxpaying population.

OTOH if your ordinary income ends *below* the 25% bracket, your LTCG/QD income that 'fits' in the lower bracket(s) is taxed at 0% (not at all) and only the portion that would be in the ordinary 25%-and-up brackets is taxed at 15%. IF your ordinary taxable income this year was below those brackets, or you expect next year it will be (possibly due to status/exemption/deduction changes as well as income change), then *if all else is equal* you are better off realizing the stock gain in the year(s) where some (or more) of it fits in the 0% bracket. If you're over about $400k a similar calculation applies, but you can afford more reliable advice than potential dogs on the Internet.

(update) Near dupe found: see also [How are long-term capital gains taxed if the gain pushes income into a new tax bracket?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28968/how-are-long-term-capital-gains-taxed-if-the-gain-pushes-income-into-a-new-tax-b)

Also, a warning on **estimated payments**: in general you are required to pay *most* of your income tax liability during the year (not wait until April 15); if you underpay by more than 10% or $1000 (whichever is larger) you usually owe a penalty, computed on Form 2210 whose name(?) is frequently and roundly cursed. For most people, whose income is (mostly) from a job, this is handled by payroll withholding which normally comes out close enough to your liability. If you have other income, like investments (as here) or self-employment or pension/retirement/disability/etc, you are supposed to either make estimated payments each 'quarter' (the IRS' quarters are shifted slightly from everyone else's), or increase your withholding, or a combination.

For a large income 'lump' in December that wasn't planned in advance, it won't be practical to adjust withholding. However, if this is the *only* year increased, there is a safe harbor: if your withholding this year (2016) is enough to pay *last* year's tax (2015) -- which for most people it is, unless you got a pay cut this year, or a (filed) status change like marrying or having a child -- you get until next April 15 (or next business day -- in 2017 it is actually April 18) to pay the additional amount of this year's tax (2016) without underpayment penalty. However, if you split the gain so that *both* 2016 and 2017 have income and (thus) taxes higher than normal for you, you *will* need to make estimated payment(s) and/or increase withholding for 2017.

PS: congratulations on your gain -- and on the patience to hold *anything* for 10 years!

Answer (score 3):

> If so, are there ways to reduce the amount of taxes owed? Given that it's currently December, I suppose I could sell half of what I want now, and the other half in January and it would split the tax burden over 2 years instead, but beyond that, are there any strategies for tax reduction in this scenario?

One possibility is to also sell stocks that have gone down since you bought them.  Of course, you would only do this if you have changed your mind about the stock's prospects since you bought it -- that is, it has gone down and you no longer think it will go up enough to be worth holding it.  When you sell stocks, any losses you take can offset any gains, so if you sell one stock for a gain of $10,000 and another for a loss of $5,000, you will only be taxed on your net gain of $5,000.

Even if you think your down stock could go back up, you could sell it to realize the loss, and then buy it back later at the lower price (as long as you're not worried it will go up in the meantime).  However, you need to wait at least 30 days before rebuying the stock to avoid wash sale rules.  This practice is known as [tax loss harvesting](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/taxes/08/tax-loss-harvesting.asp).